# how to load multiple json records into elasticsearch using elasticsearch-test

Tags: java, junit, elasticsearch

i am currently using elasticsearch-test for unit testing (with junit). i have one JSON file, where each line in this file holds a single JSON record. the file looks something like the following.

```
{ "id" : 1, "fname" : "john", "lname" : "doe" }
{ "id" : 2, "fname" : "john", "lname" : "smith" }
...
{ "id" : 10, "fname" : "jane", "lname" : "smith" }
```

what i want to do is load this data into test index. so i do something like the following.

```
@Before
public void setup throws Exception {
 this.esSetup = new EsSetup();
 this.esSetup.execute(
  deleteAll(),
  createIndex("my_index")
   .withSettings(fromClassPath("test/settings.json"))
   .withMapping("data", fromClassPath("test/mapping.json"))
  index("my_index", "data")
   .withSource(fromClassPath("test/data.json")));
}
```

however, when i test the number of records (documents), i only get one.

```
@Test
public void testCount() {
 assertTrue(this.esSetup.exists("my_index"));
 Long numDocs = this.esSetup.countAll();
 assertEquals(10L, numDocs); //fails, numDocs = 1
}
```

there is an annotation that one can use to do bulk data import: @ElasticsearchBulkRequest. however, i am not quite sure how to use this annotation, as there is no demonstration code. in my attempt, i tried it anyways, using something like the following.

```
@Test
@ElasticsearchBulkRequest(dataFile="test/data.json")
public void testCount() {
 assertTrue(this.esSetup.exists("my_index"));
 Long numDocs = this.esSetup.countAll();
 assertEquals(10L, numDocs); //fails, numDocs = 1
}
```

but i get an exception: Unable to manage index: nodeName must be defined.

so, my question is, is it possible to load a file with multiple JSON records (1 JSON record per line) into a test index with elasticsearch-test?

if not, it seems silly that i have to split each JSON record into its own file, and then do something like the following.

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
 this.esSetup.execute(
  index("my_index","data")
   .withSource(fromClassPath("test/data"+i+".json"))
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the class com.github.tlrx.elasticsearch.test.EsSetupTest shows how to bulk load data. the problem in my case was that my file holding JSON records did NOT specify indexing command.

for example, my JSON data file looks like the following.

```
{ "id" : 1, "fname" : "john", "lname" : "doe" }
{ "id" : 2, "fname" : "john", "lname" : "smith" }
...
{ "id" : 10, "fname" : "jane", "lname" : "smith" }
```

however, before each record, an index command should precede it. something like the following.

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "data", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "id" : 1, "fname" : "john", "lname" : "doe" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "data", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "id" : 2, "fname" : "john", "lname" : "smith" }
...
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "data", "_id" : "10" } }
{ "id" : 10, "fname" : "jane", "lname" : "smith" }
```

bulk loading of JSON data is shown in the resource folder: src/test/resources/com/github/tlrx/elasticsearch/test/data/products.json.